# Free cloud hosting for asp.net facebook apps?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, web-hosting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find web hosting that meets my requirements?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/20838/how-to-find-web-hosting-that-meets-my-requirements)

Facebook offers free app-hosting for PHP, Ruby, Node.js and Python, see https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/558/ . Does anyone know whether there is something similar for asp.net?

Comment: Facebook not offering hosting, but integrates with Heroku! This question isn't related to programming. Have you tried to use search before asking?

Answer (score 1):

**http://AppHarbor.com** is a service like Heroku but for .NET

One server instance is for free for .NET Apps, so, I would say it's even free, on opposite as you say, witch only tells how Heroku integrates well with Facebook, nothing about free hosting.